# MacOS MenuBarExtra vs iOS animation behavior

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a MenuBarExtra app I am working on and I am confused about the animation behavior. The animation is originating from the top left corner of the menu, but the same view and animation on a device is as expected. Here is my code for both the MenuBarExtra app and iOS app:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var scaleAmount = 1.0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Foo")
            .scaleEffect(scaleAmount)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(), value: scaleAmount)
            .onAppear {
                scaleAmount = 2
            }
        Text("Bar")
    }
}
```

}

[image: animation differences]

Is this just something to do with anchor points?

Edit: It must be something with scaleEffect, as the following seems to be expected:

```
    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(newText)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(), value: newText)
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    newText = "Bar"
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicated this - it seems that the initial placement is calculated while the layout is being calculated. In the Xcode preview window, it animates in from a different location:

[image]

What you can do to trigger the expected animation is to place the initial value change via an async call:

```swift
.onAppear {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    scale = 2.0
  }
}
```

This is enough for the placement calculations to be performed before the animation starts:

[image: Animation started with DispatchQueue.main.async]

Comment: Ha, yes, surprised I didn't give this or a delay shot first.